# Java nio channel data is not read correctly

Tags: java, networking, nio

I send a stream of data through a java nio channel, which is basically build like this:

```
<int:size of packet><int:packet id><packet data>
```

packet data is filled with different data types in a specific order (the packet id tells how to parse it). When I try to send some data locally it works just fine, but as soon as I try to run it on a Windows Server 2012 it reads an invalid packet size value such as negative values or far too big values:

Client output:

```
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
2988
-2032198748
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at network.ClientSocket.run(ClientSocket.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The numbers at the end are the read package sizes, where you can notice that one ridiculous number which leads to an exception while trying to prepare a buffer for it.

Server output:

```
Sending packet: network.PacketLoginAck (size: 16)
Sending packet: network.PacketPlayerData (size: 951)
Sending packet: network.PacketWorldInfo (size: 33)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2988)     // This is the first package that still worked
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Received packet: network.PacketChunkRequest (size: 24)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2518)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2741)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2966)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2449)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2769)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 1862)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2526)
Sending packet: network.PacketChunkData (size: 2353)
```

a PacketChunkRequest contains two ints, two coordinates, while the PacketChunkData also contains these two ints, plus the binary data, which is a int describing the length of the data followed by the actual data.

I send my data like this:

```
for(Packet p : packets) {
    System.out.println("Sending packet: "+p.getClass().getName()+" (size: "+p.length()+")");

    ByteBuffer b = p.getBuffer();
    while (b.hasRemaining()) {
        clientChannel.write(b);
    }
    b.clear();

    sentPackages.add(p);
}
```

This is the code for reading the packets:

```
List<ByteBuffer> packets = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

ByteBuffer bin = null;

int packetLength = 0;

while((bytesRead = channel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    buffer.flip();
    while(buffer.remaining() > 0) {
        if(packetLength == 0) {
            if(buffer.remaining() < 4) break;

            packetLength = buffer.getInt();
            System.out.println(packetLength);        // This is the output of the length
            bin = ByteBuffer.allocate(packetLength); // This is where the error happens
        }  

        int readSize = Math.min(packetLength, buffer.remaining());

        buffer.limit(buffer.position() + readSize);

        bin.put(buffer);

        buffer.limit(bytesRead);

        packetLength -= readSize;

        if(packetLength == 0) {
            bin.flip();

            packets.add(bin);
        }
    }

    byte[] remaining = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    for(int i = 0; buffer.remaining() > 0; i++) remaining[i] = buffer.get(); 

    buffer.clear();
    for(byte b : remaining) buffer.put(b);
}
```

This code tries to reconstruct the individual packages, that were sent together, by reading as much bytes into single buffers as the packet size (the first int of a package).

This error isn't always reproducable but keeps coming, but not locally (at least I never encountered it)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting out of sync with the sender. I haven't analysed your receiving code in detail, but clearly it doesn't handle every possible case and correctly read a packet length as an integer. You're reading part of a pacet as the length word. You need to reconsider your logic.

I would question why you're using NIO for this at all. Try it with a `DataInputStream`, using successively `readInt()` and `readFully()` until `EOFException` is thrown.

Comment: I use NIO because I have to handle multiple clients simultaneously and only want to react to people who are actually sending requests rather than waiting for one person, who might block everything else. So what exactly do you mean by getting out of sync? Is there some document I can look this up?

Comment: I mean you're reading part of a packet as a length word. What I said. Simple concept, no document required. You're using NIO in blocking mode, which is no different from using streams. Or else you're misusing it in non-blocking mode by using read loops instead of `select()` loops. Either way you're not accomplishing the objective stated in your comment: once you start servicing a client, all the others wait.

Comment: I do use a select loop, but it is not in this code segment. All incoming packets are handled in other threads so they don't block this one.